# Modify default hyphen bullet point in Office

Tags: microsoft-office

A quick way to add bullet points in the Office suite is to just use the hyphen + <kbd>Enter</kbd> command (it works in Stackexchange too, not pictured):

```
- AAA
- BBB
```

Now, the default bullet for this list is a hyphen, and the "Autocorrect" feature just takes care of the spacing and the formatting to turn it into a list.

**How do I change the default symbol?**

In my particular case, I want to use an en-dash, but it would be nice if I could change it to whatever I liked.